# Given several flow lines, find a suitable vector field equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, vector-fields, flow

So for this problem there's a number of curves in a bounded region that represents a fluid flow. The green point is a source and the fusian point is a sink. I need the fluid to flow exactly along these curves - starting at the green point - and reaching the fusian point at exactly the same time. So the outer curves would have greater velocity right? Should I use bernouilli's equation? Can I define a vector field in terms of several distinct equations. I'm struggling mightily here to finish this problem. The set K, containing all my parametric curves is: K={Φ1,Φ2,Φ3,...,phi7}.

[image]

Comment: Find velocity at any point on the streamline using these [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function). Then find the total time of travel of a fluid particle along the streamline by path integration: $\int d\mathbf{s}\cdot\mathbf{u}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the flow is incompressible, the solution to this problem all depends on the values you assign to the stream function for each of the streamlines.  The difference in stream function between two adjacent streamlines is equal to the volumetric throughput rate between them.  The residence time for the flow encompassed by two adjacent streamlines is equal to the spatial volume between the streamlines divided by the volumetric throughput rate between them.  So you just make the differences in stream function proportional to the spatial volume between adjacent streamlines.  How you would achieve such a flow is an entirely separate matter.